# How to properly escape a string in a vimrc file

Tags: vimrc, regular-expression

I am trying to add in a regex that matches either:

```
u'...'
```

or:

```
u"..."
```

To highlight the `u` before the string (it's a python thing).

This is what I have so far:

```
autocmd Syntax python syn match pythonUni       "\<\zsu\ze'" + '\|"'
```

Yet this gives me an invalid syntax when opening the python file. What would be the proper way to say `'` or `"` in a vim regex?

I tested this out and the proper regex should be:

```
/\<\zsu\ze['"]
```

But I'm not sure how to put it in the quoted command above.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `:syn match` is not really a string, but a regex. Even though it's most often delimited by double quotes, you can use any other delimiters, such as slashes or pluses.

See [`:help :syn-pattern`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-pattern):

> In the syntax commands, a pattern must be surrounded by two identical characters. This is like it works for the `:s` command.  The most common to use is the double quote. But if the pattern contains a double quote, you can use another character that is not used in the pattern.

So in your case you can simply use:

```
syn match pythonUni /\<\zsu\ze['"]/
```

Or:

```
syn match pythonUni +\<\zsu\ze['"]+
```